# Can't convert int to byte

Tags: c#, int, substring, byte, delphi-7

I'm in the process of converting a Delphi app to C#, and I came across this:

```
alength:=1; //alength is a byte
aa:=astring //astring is a string parameter passed into the function containing all this

alength:=strtoint(copy(aa,2,length(aa)-1));
```

So `copy` creates a string from part of an existing string, with the first character of the string starting at index `1`, not `0` like other languages. It uses this format:

`function copy ( Source : string; StartChar, Count : Integer ) : string;`

And then `strtoint` which converts a `string` to an `int`.

For my c# conversion of that bit of code, I have:

`alength = Convert.ToInt32(aa.Substring(1 ,aa.Length - 1));`

which gives me the error `Error 131 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Since `alength` is already type byte, I didn't think I had to cast it?

Comment: You might like my trick for [porting pascal typed arrays to .NET generics](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90819/porting-delphi-typed-arrays-to-net-generics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `Convert.ToInt32()` when you're assigning a byte. Use `Convert.ToByte()` instead.

Even better would be to use `TryParse` instead to avoid exceptions when the string isn't valid:

```
byte alength;
bool success = Byte.TryParse(aa.SubString(1,aa.Length - 1), out alength);
```

If the parsing succeedded `success` will be true, otherwise false.
You can define the flow of your program depending on whether the conversion succeeds or not:

```
byte alength;
if(Byte.TryParse(aa.SubString(1,aa.Length - 1), out alength))
{
   //Great success! continue program
}
else
{
   //Oops something went wrong! 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change:

```
alength = Convert.ToInt32(aa.Substring(1 ,aa.Length - 1));
```

into

```
alength = Convert.ToByte(aa.Substring(1 ,aa.Length - 1));
```

But more important question here would be: what is the range of value for aa string in the original use? Is it 0-255? If it is, then you can simply use `ToByte`, but if it is not, then you should think of using other data type.

Something like this:

```
int alength = Convert.ToInt32(aa.Substring(1 ,aa.Length - 1)); //define as int
```

Comment: Wait, I didn't even see the next line of the code which is `int alength32 = alength;` So the `int` to `byte` and back to `int` is redundant and I can just do as you said right?

Comment: Ah yes, if the final aim is to be `int`. that means you can immediately use `alength32` and use `Convert.ToInt32` as I put in the answer. Don't change from `int` to `byte` and then to `int` again. It *is* redundant

Comment: Thank you, I feel stupid I was stuck looking at that one line and didn't bother reading the next which would have helped.

Comment: No problem. ;) as it is often said, "sometimes, it needs a third eye to spot a mistake"

Answer (score 0):

The pure cast can also work.

The byte is approx max 255 combinations I belive, so:

```
byte i = int_variable & 0x000000FF;
```

Will be fully controled cast.

Comment: No, Visual Studio says ´Cannot convert source type "int" into target type "byte"` or you get the exception `arithmetic operation caused overflow` on runtime

Comment: Must be `byte i = (byte)(int_variable & 0x000000FF);` because your &-operation result is an integer. Maybe my compiler settings forced me to do this.

Comment: discussion: [convert unsigned 16 int in to MSB and LSB](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43cb02f4-b213-4e27-a5e2-6fef1b2e1074/convert-unsigned-16-int-in-to-msb-and-lsb?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: about the compiler setting to check for arithmetic overflow/underflow: http://rion.io/2013/04/27/enabling-underflow-and-overflow-checking-within-visual-studio/

Answer (score -2):

can use 0xFF because there is no difference & 0x000000FF == 0xFF

Comment: Your comment is not related to the question.